# Control the Redux-form with the button

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am using the `Redux-form` to do a task.
This form in a form container.
In the form container or in the form component. 
There are two buttons. An add button and a subtract button.
The form component is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
import RaisedButton  from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'

const renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => (
    <TextField hintText={label}
               floatingLabelText={label}
               errorText={touched && error}
               {...input}
               {...custom}
    />
)

const ActivityDetailForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting,} = props
  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <RaisedButton
            type="submit"
            disabled={pristine || submitting}
            label="saveChange"
            fullWidth={true}
            secondary={true}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'ActivityDetailForm',  // a unique identifier for this form
})(ActivityDetailForm)
```

Now, I face a problem. When I click the add button,

```
    <div>
      <Field name="field1" component={renderTextField} label="text1: "/>
    </div>
```

the code above will be created in the  `form` element.

When I click the add button again, the  `div` element which includes the `Field` named `field2` will be created in the `form` element.

...   `Field` named `field3`
 ...   `Field` named `field4`
 ...   `Field` named `field5`
 ...
When I click the subtract button. The last `Field` element will be destroyed.

Do you know the method to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to use the add and subtract buttons to dynamically add form elements?

Comment: @Dennis YES.  How to use the `FieldArray` to achieve it?    http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/FieldArray.md/

Answer (score 0):

The following (untested) is a pretty basic example on how to achieve dynamic inputs with a FieldArray. You'd have to tweak this a bit to tailor it to your specific scenario.

```
const renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => (
    <TextField hintText={label}
               floatingLabelText={label}
               errorText={touched && error}
               {...input}
               {...custom}
    />
)

const ActivityDetailForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting,} = props

  const renderFieldArray = ({ fields }) => (
    <div>
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          onTouchTap={() => fields.push({})}
          label="Add"
        />
      </div>
      {fields.map((field, index) => (
        <div>
          <div key={index}>
            <Field
              name={`${field}.name`}
              label={`Text ${index + 1}`}
              component={renderTextField}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <RaisedButton
              onTouchTap={() => fields.remove(index)}
              label="Remove"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <FieldArray
          name="textFields"
          component={renderFieldArray}
        />

        <RaisedButton
          type="submit"
          disabled={pristine || submitting}
          label="saveChange"
          fullWidth={true}
          secondary={true}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'ActivityDetailForm',  // a unique identifier for this form
})(ActivityDetailForm)
```